# Minecraft eventhandler triggered by command

Tags: java, command, minecraft, eventhandler

I'm creating a really simple plugin for minecraft to freeze player. I got it to work alltime to all players, but how can i make command do trigger it to specific player?

```
@EventHandler
public void Move(PlayerMoveEvent event){
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Sinut on jäädytetty tutkinnan ajaksi.");
    Location back = new Location(event.getFrom().getWorld(), event.getFrom().getX(), event.getFrom().getY(), event.getFrom().getZ());
    event.getPlayer().teleport(back);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call playerMove event

```
getServer().getPluginManager().callEvent(...);
```

Better way will be to create playerObject that save first location before teleport and then  on command call that location on teleport cause i think that normal event call will be useless there. (You want create /back command, right?)